# Angular 2 Typings Issue for XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, typescript-typings

I am using the XMLHttpRequest object to upload images.I am using WebStorm as an editor. Here is the code:

```
    uploadUserImage (files: File[], callback : any): void {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("File", files[i], files[i].name);
    }

    xhr.open('POST', this._baseUrl + '/users/images', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-jwt-token', this._securityService.getJwt());
    xhr.onload = function(){
        callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

The problem is that in the callback I am passing this.responseText. WebStorm is identifying this object as an XMLHttpRequestEventTarget. When I try to run NPM Start I get an error:

> error TS2339: Property 'responseText' does not exist on type 'XMLHttpRequestEventTarget'.

I think I need to add it to typings but I'm not sure what to add. Any ideas?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15101) tracking this. Before it get fixed, you can use

```
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
});
```

to get rid of the type error.

On the other hand, if you're using angular, you should not need to use XMLHttpRequest directly. [@angular/http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html) is a better choice.